# How does a Photocell/Photoresistor work?

Tags: electric-circuits, material-science, electrical-resistance, photoelectric-effect

I'm just curious highschooler beginning an interest in electronics and this concept of light detecting resistance component is really intriguing to me. I assume it's an application of the Photoelectric effect but how exactly does a CdS [photoresistor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoresistor) (aka LDR) do what it does.

[image: Common CdS LDR]

How can two metal wires and and a zig zag of cadmium on silicon create a light sensitive resistor? What is happening here?

How does a common Photocell really work?

Edit: I've read the wikipedia page and a whole lot of other sources but I wish for a more technical and in depth of the mechanism. Thank you :D

My biggest question is why CdS... why not anything else?

Comment: Did you read [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoresistor)? It explains the basic functioning of an LDR quite well. If you want a more detailed explanation probably about the function of CdS , specify it in the question.

Comment: Hi Nick. This sort of *tell me about XXX* question isn't well suited to the Physics SE because the answer would in effect be a blog post rather than a concise answer. You need to read the Wikipedia article udiboy suggests and maybe do some additional Googling around the subject. Then come back to us if you have specific questions.

Comment: @JohnRennie: I did, but it doesn't explain HOW it works precisely. Wikipedia says: `In the dark, a photoresistor can have a resistance as high as a few megaohms (MΩ), while in the light, a photoresistor can have a resistance as low as a few hundred ohms` ... I can't seem to find any explanation as to how that occurs.

Comment: Nick: the Wikipedia article says *If incident light on a photoresistor exceeds a certain frequency, photons absorbed by the semiconductor give bound electrons enough energy to jump into the conduction band. The resulting free electrons (and its hole partners) conduct electricity, thereby lowering resistance*. There are links to explain what semiconductors are, and what the valence and conduction bands are. All semi-conductors are light sensitive to some degree - cadmium sulphide is chosen because it's band gap happens to be just right.

Comment: @udiboy: Well, I basically wanted to know how this thing detects photons and why the zig zag. From what Mr.Rennie says, it's to facilitate electron jumping but why that design of all designs?

Comment: @JohnRennie: An elaboration on that is exactly what I require. A detailed analysis of why it works is what I want as opposed to just how it works.

Comment: Nick: for that I'm afraid you'll have to Google. In effect you're asking us to write an essay length article on CdS photoresistors when the information is but a Google away.

Comment: @JohnRennie: :D Ok, ok, I get it. I never needed a meticulous answer but an answer would have been nice nonetheless. Sorry for being too broad.